# How does this matrix multiplication code work?

Tags: java, loops, multidimensional-array, nested-loops, matrix-multiplication

This code is supposed to multiply two matrices which it does. This was for a homework assignment that I got 100 on it because my buddy helped me out.

But I'm trying to actually understand how it works and I keep getting confused for some reason. I don't really understand what the third for loop is doing.

```
        int mA = matrix1.length;
        int nA = matrix1[0].length;
        int mB = matrix2.length;
        int nB = matrix2[0].length;
        if (nA != mB){
            return null;


        double[][] C = new double[mA][nB];
        for (int i = 0; i < mA; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < nB; j++)
                for (int k = 0; k < nA; k++)
                    C[i][j] += matrix1[i][k] * matrix2[k][j];
        return C;
```

Comment: I think this isn't really a programming question, rather a math one. The third loop is simply saying that the new matrix (C) at position k,l, will have the value of the scalar product of one vector of A and one vector of B. If you draw it you will understand

Answer (score 1):

You are implementing matrix multiplication.

You can find a good explanation on [Java With Us](http://www.javawithus.com/programs/matrix-multiplication)